# Read and run Select-String cmdLet in network folder, write to local folder

Tags: powershell, access-rights, powershell-core

Am at last getting my script working as intended. Hopefully last issue is that i have only read-access to a network drive. This is okay since it is a somewhat critical place to operate in. Makes me want to write the output to a local folder instead, without trying to delete the original files.

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)
$filter  = 'M:\ALM.\*.alm'
$pattern = "ASE|MBE|MB1|Network interfaces|Handle|default collector|Proficy|Recovered|AlmODBC|Close Digital Point|DataBlock|Channel|Record|TESTBOOL|OK|OPC|Item|_COMMCHECK_|SYSTEM|ADMINISTRATOR|Unknown|ItemID|Field's|Connection|hutdown|acknowledged|Alarming|Suspended|primary|SAC|reloaded|Fix32|1601-01-01"

(Select-String -encoding $encoding -Path $filter -Pattern $pattern -NotMatch) |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {Remove-Item $filter} -Process {
      $_.line | Out-File -Append -Encoding $encoding $_.filename 
    }
```

What i don't under stand is how to make this part:`{$_.line | Out-File -Append -Encoding $encoding $_.filename }`
append the result to new *local* files with the same name, and leave the original alone apart from being read. Peace!

Update: 
My problem was what the second comment helped me solve: construct a local path as part of the `Out-File` call. I replaced `$_.filename`with `(Join-Path $LocalDir $_.filename)` and that did it.

The script works perfectly, but still tries to delete (or just edit?)the network-folder files though. Making the terminal shine up red for every file.

Update:
Corrected this be removing the whole `-Begin {Remove-Item $filter}` part.

-all your base are belong to us

Comment: Are you saying that the `{Remove-Item $filter}` block is not removing files then?

Comment: Are you asking how to construct a local path as part of the `Out-File` call? `Out-File -Append -Encoding $encoding (Join-Path $LocalDir $_.filename)`.